# ImportError: /home/me/anaconda3/envs/sniptest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5

Tags: python, pyqt5, ubuntu-20.04

When i try to run this code as shown in this link https://github.com/harupy/snipping-tool/blob/master/multi_snipping_tool.py, I got the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/Projects/sniptest/src/multisnip.py", line 36, in 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: /home/me/anaconda3/envs/sniptest/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWidgets.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5

My ubuntu version is 20.04 and I created an environment as well, which is using python 3.9. My PyQt5 version is 5.15.7

Does anyone recieved this error and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have added more information to my original post

Comment: I downgrade PyQT5 to 5.13.0 and the code managed to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/stepjam/PyRep/issues/76

From the first answer, conda remove qt-main and the code also managed to work.

```
conda list | grep 'qt'

Check what packages do you have with qt

conda remove --force <INSERT_EACH_PACKAGE> (--force only removes the package and not its dependencies)

try to run it again
```